# Data sharing between C# application by C library

Tags: c#, c, console-application, data-interchange

I have here very specific problem, which I cannot seen ever in my practice, I hope that you can help me to show what I doing wrong:

So, whe have two C-sharp console applications, and one library, which has shared memory segment and is used to data (i.e status bits) interchange.

In the library it (for simplicity I cannot post full code, there is little bit more things) looks like this:

```
#pragma data_seg("shared")
int hbStatus = 0;
bool hbExit = false;
#pragma data_seg()
#pragma comment(linker, "/SECTION:shared,RWS")

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall SetHBStatus(int status)
{
    hbStatus = status;
}
```

And similar `int GetHBStatus()` which returns `hbStatus`, and getter and setter for `hbExit` one

In main application (named "master") is imported status getter and exit setter, like this

```
class Program
    {
       const string dllimport = @"interchange.dll";
       [DllImport(dllimport)]
        public static extern int GetHBStatus();
       [DllImport(dllimport)]
        public static extern void SetHBExit(bool value);
...
```

In slave application (HB.exe) is imported `SetHBStatus` and `GetHBExit` and have this logic:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Initialize(); //after initialize, SetHBStatus is set to 1 if succeed, otherwise -1
            InitializeHeartbeatTimer(); //timer period is set in initialize and thorows an events, which doing main logic, so we may have empty while cycle
            while (!GetHBExit()) { }
            Console.WriteLine("HB exit status: " + GetHBExit());
            Console.ReadLine();
            Deinitialize();
            hbTimer.Dispose();
```

and this status is used for master app to proceed:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS!");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
Console.WriteLine("Invoking heartbeat application");
try
{         
    Process.Start(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\HB.exe");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to invoke HB application. Ending...");
    Console.WriteLine("Message: " + e.Message);
    break;
}
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS!");
SetHBExit(false); //clearing junk in library, if any
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
Console.WriteLine("Waiting for HB app initializes");
while (GetHBStatus() == 0) //waiting for response HB.exe
{ }
if (GetHBStatus() > 0)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS! Heartbeat send and ticking by interval");
}
if (GetHBStatus() < 0)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine("HB application fails. Check HB_log.txt for more details. Ending...");
    break;
}
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
Console.WriteLine("Generating file for.....
...
```

And if we need to tell HB application to deinitialize and kill itself, we will call from master and THIS call I'm doing on ONLY one place, and there is the problem (`hbStatus` in library has "1" flag, in its `Deini`t is setting `hbStatus` to "0"), which expecting master, like this:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
Console.WriteLine("Disconnecting heartbeat");
SetHBExit(true);
while (GetHBStatus() > 0) { }
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.WriteLine("HB killed and disconnected");
Console.WriteLine("\nAll disconnected, invoking main menu");
ShowOptions();
```

And now is my problem: When I execute an master application, it invokes HB.exe, let it initialize, HB returns success flag, master will continue in normal work, but HB suddenly ends on Deinit and closes itself, as received Exit flag, but the flag NOTHING and NOBODY sets by calling appropriate function (and message about disconnecting and killing is not shown).

When I try to import SetHBExit to HB.exe, and call with false after initialization, problem still appear.

This only can be seen on 32-bit applications and library, if I compile it to 64 version, applications runs smoothly and as good as needed. But, I cannot use the 64-bit version, because applications is for my client, who cannot run it in the 64 version (it also be strange problem, he has a W7 in 64 bit, but receives BadImageFormatException while program try to first call the library function (and in my machine it runs properly. Strange, strange)

Any suggestions where I'm be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Update & possible solution:

"Old" C does not support "bool" type as is, if I use a BOOL, which is typedef int, 32-bit application runs properly. So I'm considering this problem as solved :)

Secondary problem still with 64-bit application on 64-bit machine still remains unsolved, BadImageFormat exception, but on my machine it works great